# How do i centre the animated "scroll down" indicator on the image but between grass and floor

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do i centre the animated "scroll down" indicator on the image
but between grass and floor.
In the css this is indicated by the .indicator class.
I have tried justify and text align centre to see if this would work but it hasn't.

http://www.toonsville.co.uk/

```
 /*controls for drop down indicator*/
```

```css
.indicator {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.indicator span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: none;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
  animation: animate 1s linear infinite;
}

.indicator span:nth-child(1) {
  top: -30px;
  left: -30px;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  border-color: goldenrod;
}

.indicator span:nth-child(2) {
  top: -15px;
  left: -15px;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  border-color: greenyellow;
}

.indicator span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  border-color: orange;
}

.indicator span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  animation-delay: 0.6s;
  border-color: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div class="looneys">
  <img src="images/nobackgroundmotion-Recovered2.png" width="100%">
  <div class="indicator">

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Please post your code in your question and explain a bit more what your issue is and what you want. External links have a tendency to break, and since they aren't verifiable, members correctly are hesitant to click.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, i have now done this.

Comment: focus on the details and no need to add noises to your question like *I am newbie* or *thanks* .. and the CSS code alone is not enough, we need full code HTML/CSS

Comment: Note that you can use Stack Snippets to show us here on Stack Overflow. When you [edit] your question, click on the button that looks like a page with `<>` on it. You'll get places to put HTML and CSS. Please do try and limit the code to just enough to demonstrate the problem, not your whole app.

Comment: ok i have used the edit now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding to your indicator class:

```
position: absolute;
transform: rotate(45deg) translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
left: 50%;
bottom: 70px;
z-index: 1;
```

Comment: Bro, you are amazing, thanks so much. At the moment, when i try to make it responsive, i notice that the indicator is not contained within the image itself, any idea how to do this?

Comment: you can add `position: relative;` to the looneys class

Comment: My Goodness, you are awesome, thank you so much, i hope i can be like you one day.